# Windows 8 hangs at splash screen during startup

Tags: windows-8, freeze

I recently formatted my SSD and installed a fresh copy of Windows 8 64bit. However, when restarting or turning the pc off and on, windows will hang at the splash screen such that the rotating icon will get stuck. Once I reset the PC, it says it will start auto repair but the rotating icon also freezes. If I try to boot from the install CD, the CD loading will also hang indefinitely.

The solution so far has been to unplug the power for a few minutes and then turn the PC on. I suspect it might be something to do with the motherboard BIOS or the SSD. My specs are:

Motherboard: ASRock G41M-VS3 R2.0, 
SSD: Sandisk SSD Extreme 120gb

Comment: After unplugging the power and restarting, does Windows offer to repair or just boot up?

Comment: I think it just boots normally. I don't actually remember that well. I know that it seems to alternate between a normal boot and an automatic repair boot when startup isn't working. I'll test more tonight.

Comment: And this happens every time the power is cycled or the PC is reset, or intermittently?

Answer (score 1):

Create a bootable USB using win2flash. Once you have it, delete both bootmgr.efi and the folder efi from the root of your USB. I had the same issue, my laptop hanged when I booted the installation of Windows 8, but after deleting these two files, the installation continued flawlessly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few questions I'd like you to respond to. 
1) Has the fresh copy of Windows on your recently formatted SSD ever worked before it started freezing? 
2) When you wait a few minutes and turn it back on does it do the same thing over and over again (boot to splash or win CD and hang there)? 
3) When booting from the CD, how far do you get before it hangs up, are you even able to get to the main menu?

Instinct tells me it was a bad installation, have you tried re-formatting and re-installing?  I need some more information to visualize what's going on that we don't see.

Comment: 1) Yes, the initial install appeared to work fine and I was able to boot into the OS and install some programs. The first time I restarted, the error started occurring. When I was finally able to boot into the install DVD, I ran a refresh of the OS.

2) I have tried waiting a few minutes before turning it back on however it didn't seem to work. However, this morning I was able to boot the PC fine after leaving it off overnight and NOT unplugging.

3) When booting from the CD, it does not even make it to the main menu.

I will test some more tonight.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it got fixed but it seems to work fine now. I did try disabling Fast Boot but the restart immediately after still had issues. Maybe it takes longer to go into effect.  Sorry for the trouble.